# I have two tables i want to join them in my SQL to retrieve results

Tags: sql

[image]

i have two table ork3,ork2 i want to sum column k1 join table ork3>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: It literally looks like your question has been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216209/query-to-sum-from-two-different-tables

Comment: i think read Carefully my question

Comment: shouldn't the results in sum(K1) for name = a be 7 rather than 6?

Comment: You are asking one thing in your title and asking another in your description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to sum from two different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216209/query-to-sum-from-two-different-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT [name]
    , [date]
    , [dep]
    , [sum(k1)]
FROM   ork3
      INNER JOIN
              (SELECT [name]
                   , SUM([k1]) AS [sum(k1)]
               FROM   ork2
               GROUP BY [name]) AS ork2 ON ork3.[name] = ork2.[name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do;

```
Select name, sum(k1) From ork3 o3 Inner Join ork2 o2 On o2.name = o3.name group by o3.name;
```